# Chaining the jQuery index() function

Tags: jquery, chaining

I have the following code:

```
var td = textbox.closest('tr').children('td:first');
```

I want to get the index of the closest tr withind a table and set it to a variable so I'd need to put the index() function bewteen closest('tr') and children('td:first');. Something like this:

```
var td = textbox.closest('tr').index(/*PUT A FUNCTION HERE */).children('td:first');
```

I know I can accomplish this just like this way:

```
var index = textbox.closest('tr').index();
```

but I was wondering whether is possible to make it using chaining method.

Comment: You're already chaining there. Have you tried doing what you want?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I've tried and I get a runtime exception because Rocket says.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Why do you want to chain `index()`?  `closest('tr')` will return 1 element, and `.index()` will get it's position in its parent element.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i want to set 2 values to 2 variables in one instruction. Because of this i suggest to make the index() value assingment with and embedded function inside index()

Comment: @senyortoni: Sorry, but you can't do that.  Well, I guess you could make your own jQuery plugin to do it, but I think it would be more readable to just make it in multiple statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function returns a number, not a jQuery object.  You can't chain it.